# Error when attempting to write cProfile information to file

Tags: python-2.7, cprofile, pstats

I am attempting to load a cProfile profile, do some sorting and finessing, then output the results to a file.  Based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#the-stats-class), I thought I could simply pass a file object and the `print_stats` function would redirect to that stream.

Here is the code I am attempting to use:

```
import sys,pstats
s = open('output.txt', 'w')
p = pstats.Stats('profile.dat', s)
```

and here is the resulting error:

```
TypeError: Cannot create or construct a <class pstats.Stats at 0xbaa870> object from '<open file 'output.txt', mode 'w' at 0xb2ef60>''
```

I should also add that when I do not pass an object to the stream parameter, the output appears as normal in the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code, you'd have to pass the file as a `stream` keyword argument (not clear to me why it was implented like that...), like:

```
p = pstats.Stats('profile.dat', stream = s)
```

See below the inline comment, and the `if "stream" in kwds` line.

```
class Stats:
    """..."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # I can't figure out how to explictly specify a stream keyword arg
        # with *args:
        #   def __init__(self, *args, stream=sys.stdout): ...
        # so I use **kwds and sqauwk if something unexpected is passed in.
        self.stream = sys.stdout
        if "stream" in kwds:
            self.stream = kwds["stream"]
            del kwds["stream"]
        if kwds:
            keys = kwds.keys()
            keys.sort()
            extras = ", ".join(["%s=%s" % (k, kwds[k]) for k in keys])
            raise ValueError, "unrecognized keyword args: %s" % extras
        if not len(args):
            arg = None
        else:
            arg = args[0]
            args = args[1:]
        self.init(arg)
        self.add(*args)
```

Comment: I have the stream propery assigned (http://dpaste.com/2R8YS04) but the same error arise.

Comment: @tutuca please post your code, or ask a new question